# Performance Sqoop with the DEI Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

We are facing a big performance problem here in the company where I work for processing in the Data Engennering Integration tool of the Informatica supplier.
Currently our biggest problem is the slow process with sqoop for data collection in oracle.

140 million records take more than 1 hour to execute.
My arguments for the sqoop connection are as follows.

`--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOSTNAME:PORT/INSTANCE_ORACLE`

Would anyone know to indicate a sqoop setting for me to improve the extraction performance?

Thanks,
Gustavo Visachi

Comment: I am confused, do you use Informatica to ingest or sqoop to ingest. If you are using sqoop to get from oracle - 1. you can use bulk mode, 2. you can sqoop in raw format and then convert it to normal table. We are using method #2 which is really fast 100million may 10/15min.

Comment: Here, I use Integration with Informatica data engineer to collect Oracle data and complete it in files on HDFS (Hadoop). The sqoop connection is created within the DEI tool (BDM). I don't know if I can pass any more parameters on the connection created to gain performance.

Comment: hmm, then more mappers may help. This is a generic setting and hopefully will speed up the sqoop. Pls talk to hdfs admin on how many maximum mappers can be used.

Comment: Good morning, how are you?

Here we can use up to 10 mappings.

Example:

--num-mappers 10 --split-by DW_NUM_NTC

The mapping runs in 14 minutes in the pre-run that data engineering informatica, however the extraction for recording on the parquet takes an hour on average for 167 million records. We are finding it very slow.

Comment: can you try to load into text file. Because text format is faster. Parquet is compressed format and sometime impala need to compress the data after sqooping in. create a test table in text format and then start sqoop in with that. 1hour seems high.